# spinner not show after submit the button

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, ajaxform

When I will submit the form data without any error than spinner showing... but when the form have some error (like username is required) and after submit the form than spinner not showing...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spinner = $('#loader');

      $(document).on('submit', '#payment-form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        spinner.show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'post_create' %}",
            data: {
                title: $('#id_title').val(),
                ages: $('#id_ages').val(),
                zip_codes: $('#id_zip_codes').val(),
                address_user: $('#id_address_user').val(),
                phone: $('#id_phone').val(),
                state: $('#id_state').val(),
                city: $('#id_city').val(),
                category: $('#id_category').val(),
                description: $('#id_description').val(),
                photo_main: $('#id_photo_main').val(),    
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            error:function('#card-element'){
                spinner.fadeOut();
            },
            success:function(data){
                spinner.fadeOut();
            }
        });

      });
  </script>
```

Comment: So there is a validation script somewhere. Please post it too.

Comment: yes, i'm also using stripe default payment script. @LouysPatriceBessette